# Bind commands to key-up and key-down in AutoHotkey

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, key-binding

I have written two functions in an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script: `fun1()` and `fun2()`. I now need to bind `fun1()` to when <kbd>Pause</kbd> is pressed down, and bind `fun2()` to when <kbd>Pause</kbd> is released.

As an example, I would press and hold <kbd>Pause</kbd> to hide all windows, and release <kbd>Pause</kbd> to restore all windows. (This example is not my actual objetive).

**How can I do that in AutoHotkey?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compile your .ahk scripts as .exe. Then have

```
Pause::C:\fun1.exe    
Pause Up::C:\fun2.exe
```

More info on .akh to .exe: [autohotkey- ahk2exe](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe)

Comment: Actually, compiling them is unnecessary. I already defined them as functions. My question regarded specifically to the key up/down syntax. I wasn't finding it in the manual, so I asked here. Eventually I found a couple examples online, and it's exactly what you said except there's a blank space between "pause" and "up/down".

Comment: No need to add `Down` since its the default trigger. Only `Up` must be specified

Comment: Wrong. Long press of Pause will send multiple "keyDown" evens, launching `C:\fun1.exe ` multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish the desired functionality with this code:

```
pause::
    fun1()
    keyWait, pause
    fun2()
return
```

If you are dealing with subroutines instead, use this:

```
pause::
    gosub, sub1
    keyWait, pause
    gosub, sub2
return
```

Comment: This is right answer. Because it handles long press without sending mulltiple "keyDown" events.